# error message when executed in DolphinDB gui

Tags: dolphindb

run code in gui as below

```
db= database("dfs://bonds_txb")
```

error message: FileBlock[*]returned from name node didn't contain any site

why?

Answer (score 0):

This database is not ready to be loaded. Please wait until it is loaded and ready to be accessed.